# Create Shapely linestring from string of coordinates in text format

Tags: python, shapely, geopandas, fiona

I have a DataFrame where one column consists of lines stored like so:

```
'[[-7.61, 42.15],[-6.62, 43.16],[-8.9, 41.0],[-9.2, 40.5]]'
```

Is there an easy way to read these lines directly into shapely LineStrings so I can treat this as a GeoDataFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I just sorted it out, though I am happy for suggested improvements:

```
line = '[[-7.61, 42.15],[-6.62, 43.16],[-8.9, 41.0],[-9.2, 40.5]]'

import ast
line = LineString(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

Comment: That looks JSON-y so you could also do `line = LineString(json.loads(text))`

Comment: Great, thanks! Even better without another library.